# A scriptManager (singleton) not storing a variable (in the same scene)

Tags: unity, c#

The script below is called every time I pickup an item and stores an instance of it in the array "mainInventory".

The problem is when I access the array after picking up another item its empty.

The script is on the MainCamera.

```
public class InventoryManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public static InventoryManager instance = null;
public Image inventoryPanel0;
public Image inventoryPanel1;
public Image inventoryPanel2;
public Image inventoryPanel3;
public Image inventoryPanel4;
public Image inventoryPanel5;
public Image inventoryPanel6;

private Item[] mainInventory;


// Use this for initialization
void Awake ()
{
    //Singleton
    if (instance == null)
        instance = this;
    else if (instance != this)
        Destroy(gameObject);

    mainInventory = new Item[7];
}

public void pickedUp(Item item)
{
    //Below checks which slot item belongs in
    bool positionFound = false;
    int currentPositionCheck = 0;

    while (!positionFound)
    {
        if (mainInventory[currentPositionCheck] == null)
            positionFound = true;
        else
            currentPositionCheck++;    
    }

    //Adds item to slot
    mainInventory[currentPositionCheck] = item;

    //Adds image to inventory panel
    switch (currentPositionCheck)
    {
        case 0:
            inventoryPanel0.sprite = item.icon;
            break;
        case 1:
            inventoryPanel1.sprite = item.icon;
            break;
        case 2:
            inventoryPanel2.sprite = item.icon;
            break;
        case 3:
            inventoryPanel3.sprite = item.icon;
            break;
        case 4:
            inventoryPanel4.sprite = item.icon;
            break;
        case 5:
            inventoryPanel5.sprite = item.icon;
            break;
        case 6:
            inventoryPanel6.sprite = item.icon;
            break;
        default:
            Debug.LogError("Expand inventory", this);
            break;
    }


}
}
```

Item:

```
public class Item : MonoBehaviour {

public string name;
public Sprite icon;

private MessageManager messageManagerScript;
private InventoryManager inventoryManagerScript;
private bool inRange;


private void Start()
{
    //Gets managers
    GameObject managerContainer = GameObject.FindWithTag("MainCamera");
    if (managerContainer != null)
    {
        inventoryManagerScript = managerContainer.GetComponent<InventoryManager>();
        messageManagerScript = managerContainer.GetComponent<MessageManager>();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Can't find camera containing maangers");
    } 
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    //If in range and player presses key
    if (inRange && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        OnTriggerExit(new Collider());

        //Pickup item
        inventoryManagerScript.pickedUp(this);
    }

}


private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    inRange = true;

    //Displays pickup message
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        messageManagerScript.displayPickupMessage(name);
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    //Removes pickup message
    messageManagerScript.removeDisplayMessage();

    inRange = false;
}
```

}

Comment: Is `Item` a `MonoBehaviour` subclass? Or anything else related to `UnityEngine.Object`?

Comment: @Ed Marty Nope, I've added to above.

Comment: I think you mean yes. Item is a `MonoBehaviour` subclass, as shown in your code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Destroy(gameObject)` it destroys the `gameObject` as well as the components on it, including the `Item`. Later, when you are looking for an empty spot in the list, you check for the object being null. When comparing a `MonoBehaviour` that has been destroyed to null, it returns true.

So your problem is that you are destroying the `Item`. Maybe you should just be disabling it, or putting something besides the `MonoBehaviour` into your inventory list.